# Android OpenGL ES 2 and armeabi-v7a

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, armv7

My Android app requires `OpenGL ES 2`.

Should I only build for `armeabi-v7a`?

Or are there `ARMv5` or `ARMv6` devices which support `OpenGL ES 2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android 2.2 and above supports OpenGL ES 2 so you should check for APP_PLATFORM rather than APP_ABI. In short rather than checking for architecture, check for Android version.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html#compatibility

Comment: Actually, I'm targeting Android 4.0 and up.  I'm wondering if I still _should_ build for both `armeabi` and `armeabi-v7a`.

Comment: In my experience, this has nothing to do with OpenGl ES 2. That depends on the devices that you wish to target. If you can find any device that is above Android 2.2 and has armv5 architecture, then go for it. But I doubt there is any device that is above Android 4.0 and uses Armv5 as this list suggests:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1596800

And you can use http://pdadb.net/ to find out the list of devices for armeabi.

Comment: OpenGL ES 2.0 support has nothing to do with ARMv5 architecture. On practice, however, it is quite hard to find such ancient devices w/ ARMv5 CPUs and most likely they won't have Android 4 you are targeting at. But anyways, is it that hard to include support for both v5 and v7a chips? We've added x86 to our /libs, however I haven't encountered any installs on phones w/ x86 CPUs.